# Filtrar DataGrid con TextBox y ComboBox WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, wpf

Necesito filtrar un DataGrid en el que se carga un tabla SQL SERVER, y se carga de la siguiente manera

```
public GeneralPendientes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        binddatagrid();
        cmbDatos.ItemsSource = typeof(Datos).GetProperties().Select((o) => o.Name);
    }


public void binddatagrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connCompras"].ConnectionString;
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_listar_pendientes";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Pendientes");
        da.Fill(dt);

        facturasPendientesDG.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

Hice el siguiente intento para el Filtering...
Añadí una clase Datos

```
public class Datos
{
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

    public string NombreProveedor { get; set; }

    public string OC { get; set; }

    public string Facturas { get; set; }

    public string FormaPago { get; set; }

    public string FechaRecibido { get; set; }

    public string FechaPago { get; set; }

    public string MonedaMXN { get; set; }

    public string MonedaUSD { get; set; }

    public string Notas { get; set; }
}
```

Y en mi ventana xaml.cs

```
public Predicate<object> GetFilter()
    {
        switch(cmbDatos.SelectedItem as string)
        {
            case "RazonSocial":

                return RazonSocialFilter;

            case "NombreProveedor":

                return ProveedorFilter;

            case "OC":

                return OCFilter;

            case "Facturas":

                return FacturasFilter;

            case "FormaPago":

                return FormaPagoFilter;

            case "FechaRecibido":

                return FechaRecibidoFilter;

            case "FechaPago":

                return FechaPagoFilter;

            case "MonedaMXN":

                return MonedaMXNFilter;

            case "MonedaUSD":

                return MonedaUSDFilter;

            case "Notas":

                return NotasFilter;
        }

        return RazonSocialFilter;
    }

    private bool RazonSocialFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.RazonSocial.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool ProveedorFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.NombreProveedor.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool OCFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.OC.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool FacturasFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.Facturas.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool FormaPagoFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.FormaPago.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool FechaRecibidoFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.FechaRecibido.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool FechaPagoFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.FechaPago.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool MonedaMXNFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.MonedaMXN.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool MonedaUSDFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.MonedaUSD.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private bool NotasFilter(object obj)
    {
        var Filterobj = obj as Datos;
        return Filterobj.Notas.StartsWith(cmbDatos.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

private void cmbDatos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      facturasPendientesDG.Items.Filter = GetFilter();
    }

private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       GeneralPendientes p = new GeneralPendientes();
       if(p.cmbDatos.Text == null)
        {
            p.facturasPendientesDG.Items.Filter = null;
        }
       else
        {
            p.facturasPendientesDG.Items.Filter = p.GetFilter();
        }
    }
```

Me depura mi proyecto, pero al querer hacer el Filtering me cierra el proyecto por un error de incompatibilidad. Entiendo qué es por la manera en la que se carga mi tabla a mi DataGrid, pero no sé qué es lo que debo cambiar, soy un poco nueva en esto.Me podrían ayudar con esto o darme alguna otra idea de como hacer mi Filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te daré un ejemplo de se puede hacer. Craré un `TextBox` llamado "Buscar" para realizar el filtro

```
<TextBox  x:Name="Buscar" TextChanged="Buscar_TextChanged"  />
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dataGrid" />
```

Luego en la clase `Datos`, agregaré una función que retorne una lista de los valores de las propiedades por las que quiero filtrar.

```
public class Datos
{
   //Todas las otras propiedades

   public string[] StartWidthProperties()
      => new string[]{ RazonSocial, NombreProveedor, OC};
}
```

En el código anterior estoy diciendo que solo quiero buscar por `StartsWith`, las propiedades: `RazonSocial`,`NombreProveedor` y `OC`, tú puedes agregar más o menos propiedades, y/o agregar otras funciones que indiquen otro tipo de filtrado

En el MainWindow tendremos lo siguiente:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Datos> DatosList;
    ListCollectionView listCollectionView;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DatosList =new ObservableCollection<Datos>();
        //Cargo datos de prueba en DatosList, tu debes cargar desde tu base de datos
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            DatosList.Add(new Datos() { 
                RazonSocial = "RZ " + i,
                NombreProveedor = "RZ " + i,
                OC = i.ToString(),
                Facturas = "RZ " + i,
                FormaPago = "RZ " + i,
                FechaRecibido = "RZ " + i,
                FechaPago = "RZ " + i,
                MonedaMXN = "RZ " + i,
                MonedaUSD = "RZ " + i,
                Notas = "RZ " + i,
        });
            //A listCollectionView le asignamos DatosList
            listCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(DatosList);
            listCollectionView.Filter = GetFilter;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = listCollectionView;

        }
    }

    public bool GetFilter(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Datos)) return false;
        Datos? dato = obj as Datos;
        return dato!.StartWidthProperties().Any(a => StartWith(a));
    }
    public bool StartWith(string text) => text.StartsWith(Buscar.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    private void Buscar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //refresca la colección, por lo que se vuelve activar el filtro
        listCollectionView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Basicamente el truco está en usar las 2 primeras collecciones, la primera quien es la que almacenará los datos y la segunda envuelve los datos para una vista. Básicamente la relación es la siguiente
`ObservableCollection -> ListCollectionView -> DataGrid`

El resto del código, es la misma lógica que tú tienes, pero hecho de una manera que tenga menos líneas de código.

En la siguiente imagen se ve como si ingreso `1` filtra todos los elementos cuya OC comiencen con `1`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso me sirve muchísimo. ¡MUCHAS GRACIAS!